# Why does http_response_code() not work?

Tags: php, header

I'm on PHP 5.4.35.

This code:

```
<?php
http_response_code(404);
header('Location: /');
?>
```

makes my server return this answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sat, 20 Dec 2014 15:06:32 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.35
Location: /
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

### Why do I not see `404`?

---

**Edit:**

According to the answers, the `Location`-header overwrites the `404` status code. Since the page that is being called did not move temporarily, but never existed, I now supply a `301 Moved Permanently` status code with `http_response_code(301)`, which works in conjunction with the `Location`-header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a [`Location`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) header which overwrites the [404 Not Found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) with [302 Found/Moved Temporarily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) header.

Redirecting users instead of showing 404 does not make sense anyway. I would suggest that you send 404 error code so that search engines know that the page no longer exist (and remove the redirection).

And show a clickable link back to the home page (and present a site search box) so that the error page is still usable for human visitors.

Comment: I understand. But this is the code of my 404 page! I get tons of calls to pages that *never existed*, and I don't see why I should send a "moved" header for something that was not moved but never existed in the first place.

Comment: This is what I said: do not redirect visitors if they ask for something that does not exist. Redirecting instead of showing 404 errors conveys the incorrect message: the content you requested is temporarily available at */some/url*.

Comment: Okay, longer comment. This code is part of a page that displays pages of a webcomic, if it is given a page number as query string, e.g. `page.php?number=4`. Other values or other query strings are meaningless. Yet I get stuff like `page.php?number=googleb866e42cb5541931`. I am pretty sure that no user typed that into their address field, and if anyone created a link with that URL, he is an idiot. So anyone using that URL should be told that nothing is there (404), but since no human would use that URL and it is probably some spider or bot testing my site, I prefer to give them actual content.

Comment: OK, just use an if/else statement to send separate headers to humans and bots. **But this will cause additional problems such as duplicate content**. What if you feed same content to a spider that asks for `page.php?number=4`, `page.php?number=asdf1`, `page.php?number=asdf2`, ..., `page.php?number=asdf99999`? I wouldn't; I would just 404 these requests.

Comment: You are right, and I already changed my setup. Everyone gets a 404 code and error page. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, if you send the location header down, it will result in a 302 if it is not a 201 or 3xx status code.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: What does it mean to "send the location header **down**"? I have never heard that phrase.

Comment: i mean call `header` with the location header value.